# Is there a way to terminate a running process (zscroll) after the end of a while loop in a bash script

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am writing a little script which looks at the output of spotify to determine whether the music stops or starts again, refreshing title and artist after every new start of the playback. Sometimes, the song information is a bit too long, so i am using zscroll to, well, scroll through the line.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

maxlength=50


spotify --show-console 2>&1 |
grep -P --line-buffered "Playing music" |
while read line 
do  
    if [[ $line == *"true"* ]]; then
        sleep 0.3
        playerctl --player=spotify metadata --format '{{ title }} - {{ artist }}' |
        zscroll -l "$maxlength" 
#       cut -c 1-$maxlength
#       cut works wonderful, i am just missing a bit of text, so its not an option
    else
        echo "music stopped!"
    fi
done
```

This works fine, however, only for the first song. Going to the next, it just continues to scroll through the old song (i suspect there isn't even a new iteration, as the zscroll process isn't finished yet) — is there a way to terminate the running zscroll process with every iteration of the loop?

if it's about the OS - i use arch btw

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your solution is: how should `zscroll` know when the title stops playing? You read the currently playing title with `playerctl` in order to transfer it to `zscroll`. `zscroll` takes the text and displays it. Forever. Nobody informs `zscroll` that the music has been stopped.

It is probably easier to run `zscroll` the way it is intended by its author. See the example "Continually update the playing song" in the manual page of `zscroll`.

Create a script `spotify.sh`, which uses `playerctl` to read the currently played title.

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

case $(playerctl --player=spotify status) in
  Playing)
    playerctl --player=spotify metadata --format '{{ title }} - {{ artist }}'
  ;;
  Paused)
    echo "music stopped!"
  ;;
esac
```

Then start `spotify`. (I had to add the `--no-zygote` option on my system to stop `spotify` from instantly crashing.)

```
spotify &
```

And then run `zscroll` with the script.

```
zscroll -n f -u t -U 1 ./spotify.sh
```

`zscroll` calls the `spotify.sh` script in an endless loop once per second and checks for changes. Whenever the output of the script changes, the new text will be displayed. It is not necessary to parse the console output of `spotify`. The disadvantage of this solution is, that `playerctl` is executed about 480 times for a 4 minute song.

Your solution will call `playerctl` only when necessary. But your approach requires that you have to run `zscroll` in the background to be able to read the next event from the console output. Whenever a new event arrives, you have to kill the old `zscroll` background job, to start the new one with the new title text.